# How to compare 2 lists values?

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists and I would like to remove the items when the items from the first list is not present in the second list.

```
 public class ResolutionsRow
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public List<ResolutionsRow> Categories { get; set; }
```

---

In the following Category.LoadForProject(project.ID) returns an IList

```
DeleteItems(Category.LoadForProject(project.ID), Categories);
```

---

```
private void DeleteItems(dynamic currentItems, dynamic items) 
            {
                if (currentItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var existingItem in currentItems)
                    {
                        if (items.Contains(existingItem.Name))
                           items.Remove(existingItem.Name);
                    }
                } 
            }
```

I am having the error message

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Contains(MvcUI.Models.ResolutionsRow)' has some invalid arguments.  What is wrong with my code and how can I correct it? Help please.

I have tried to change the code to, but I am having the error message

> Error 6   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to API.Category'  MvcUI\Models\ProjectModel.cs    255 44  MvcUI
>   Error 5   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.Contains(API.Category)' has some invalid arguments   MvcUI\Models\ProjectModel.cs    255 24  MvcUI

---

```
var categories = Category.LoadForProject(project.ID);
                foreach (var item in Categories)
                {
                    if(categories.Contains(item.ID))
                   {

                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `items`? I'm guess it is the list of `ResolutionsRow` - so you will need to search for an item **with** that name/id, not the name/id itself.

If they are the same object instances, then just `Remove(existingItem)` will work, but otherwise (if they are different object instances that happen to have the same `.Name`):

```
items.RemoveAll(item => item.Name == existingItem.Name);
```

by the way; do you really need `dynamic` here? Without it, the compiler would tell you the problem. It isn't helping you any, and could well cause a lot of problems (explicit interface implementations, lambdas, etc - there are constructs that aren't fans of `dynamic`)

Comment: dynamic items = Categories = List<ResolutionsRow> Categories They are not object of the same instances. They both have the .Name but I still haven`t understood why i`m having the error

Comment: user281180 - because it *isn't a list of names*. It is a list of *objects*. You are attempting to remove a `string`, using a `Remove` method that accepts a `ResolutionsRow`. That just can't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the easy LINQ answer:

```
var currentItems = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 6 };
var items = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var resultItems = items.Except(currentItems); // resultItems == new int[] { 3, 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
items.Contains(existingItem.Name);
```

and

```
items.Remove(existingItem.Name);
```

to

```
items.Contains(existingItem);

items.Remove(existingItem);
```

Comment: I`m still having the error message

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcUI.Models.ResolutionsRow>.Contains(MvcUI.Models.ResolutionsRow)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: In the last code sample in your edit to the answer, change `if(categories.Contains(item.ID))` to `if(categories.Contains(item))`.  The LINQ based options others have posted are probably a better options, btw.  Do you have an issue with using LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

you want to use `items1.Except(items2)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `items.Contains` method signature is expecting a type different than what you provided.  Looks like you are providing a string instead of a ResolutionsRow.

Answer (score 0):

How often are you doing this, and with how many items in each list?  What you are doing is commonly considered a "Set operation"(union, intersection, minus, etc).  If the answer to either of the previous questions is "a lot", then you want to consider using a [SortedSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) or [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Your current implementation is O(m*n) (where m and n are the sizes of the two lists).  If you use a hash set it is O(n), since only the second set is actually iterated over.  There is also a cost to build the sets (O(m+n)), but if you have enough objects or can use it for more than just one operation it can be worth it.